# Is there a corresponding Rotate option like RotationTransform[{u,v},p]

Tags: rotation, geometric-transform

`RotationTransform` has options `RotationTransform[{u,v},p]`

> gives a rotation about the point p that transforms u to the direction
>   of v.

But why there is only `Rotate[g,{u,v}]`

How to set the point p in `Rotate`?

Comment: But there is a third argument (coordinate list}  for `Rotate` which does just that...

Comment: @YvesKlett I can't find it, which option do you mean?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html

Comment: @YvesKlett Er... I am really stupid now. But I can't find the exact same thing like `RotationTransform[{u,v},p]`. There is only `Rotate[g,{u,v}]` but without a reference point. And `Rotate[g,θ,{u,v}]` is totally different thing. Would you help me again?

Comment: From the help: "`Rotate[g,θ,{x,y}]` rotates about the point".

Comment: @YvesKlett They are not the same thing. `RotationTransform[{u,v},p]` represent rotation that will rotate vector u to vector v with reference point p.

Comment: Apologies - my bad, I misinterpreted your question. Voting to reopen. Suggestion: The question title "Why is there..." is always prone to subjective answers. Perhaps "Is there a corresponding..." might be better.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thank you, I edited my title

Answer (score 3):

You could translate the figure being rotated back and forth.

```
GeometricTransformation[g, RotationTransform[{u, v}, p]]
```

is equivalent to

```
Translate[Rotate[Translate[g, -p], {u, v}], p]
```

For example,

```
u = {1, 0};
v = {1, 1/5};
p = {1/3, 1/3};
g = Rectangle[];
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, RotationTransform[{u, v}, p]], Axes -> True]
Graphics[Translate[Rotate[Translate[g, -p], {u, v}], p], Axes -> True]
```

[image: rotated rectangle]

This works in both 2D and 3D.

Comment: `Rotate[g, VectorAngle[u, v], p]`